# filter json objects by Id in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, object, loopbackjs

I have a JSON that returns an array of arrays of objects but what I want to do is to return an array of objects filtered by ID.
This the code I built so far :

```
    let objComedien3=[];
      let i=0;

      for (var prop in bc) {
        objComedien3[i] = await app.models.cm_comediens_extraits_mp3.find({ where: { idMedia: bc[prop]} } );
        //here the result is giving me an array of arrays of objects so I had to do this :
        objComedien3[i]= Object.assign({}, objComedien3[i]);
        i++;
      }
      return objComedien3;
```

Final result I found is this :

```
[
  {
    "0": {
      "idSon": 33274,
      "idMedia": 42084,
      "qfDiffusion": null,
      "qfAccent": null,
      "qfAge": 169,
      "qfCartoon": null,
      "qfDoublage": null,
      "qfInterpretation1": 194,
      "qfInterpretation2": 194,
      "qfInterpretation3": 193,
      "qfImitation": null,
      "qfLangue": 145,
      "qfTimbre": 237,
      "qfType": 245,
      "qfGenre": "Masculin",
      "description": "Techno Music"
    }
  },
  {
    "0": {
      "idSon": 33275,
      "idMedia": 42086,
      "qfDiffusion": null,
      "qfAccent": null,
      "qfAge": 240,
      "qfCartoon": null,
      "qfDoublage": null,
      "qfInterpretation1": 196,
      "qfInterpretation2": 195,
      "qfInterpretation3": 247,
      "qfImitation": null,
      "qfLangue": 147,
      "qfTimbre": 236,
      "qfType": 176,
      "qfGenre": "Masculin",
      "description": "Techno Music"
    }
  }
]
```

Everything is fine except that I want to replace 0 by idSon and I didn't know how to manage that with Object.assign or any other function using javascript.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 let objComedien3=[];
      let i=0;

      for (var prop in bc) {
        objComedien3[i] = await app.models.cm_comediens_extraits_mp3.find({ where: { idMedia: bc[prop]} } );
        //here the result is giving me an array of arrays of objects so I had to do this :
        let data= {}
        data[objComedien3[i][0]['idSon']] = objComedien3[i][0]
        objComedien3[i]= Object.assign({}, data);
        i++;
      }
      return objComedien3;
```

Comment: But ideally you should do a `where: {idMedia: {inq: bc}}` and then get the whole resultset. and process them. This way you are not using multiple queries.

Answer (score 1):

I know there is an already accepted answer but to do this proper way, you should get the total result then process them.

```
const dataset = await app.models.cm_comediens_extraits_mp3.find(
    { where: { idMedia: {inq: bc} } }//which gets all the media
).then((data)=>{//it is an array already
    return data.reduce((p,c)=>{
        p[c.idSon] = c;//or c.__data if you want the data. Or Object.assign
        return p;
    },{})
})
```

This way you are not querying every time.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using an `object` instead of an `array`, which allows you to enter the `idSon` key as qualifier instead of an index in the `array`:

```
let objComedien3 = {};

for (var prop in bc) {
  let result = await app.models.cm_comediens_extraits_mp3.find({ where: { idMedia: bc[prop]} } );
  let clonedResult = Object.assign({}, result[0]);
  objComedien3[clonedResult.idSon] = clonedResult;
}

return objComedien3;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (let t of test) {

    //replace your "0" with new "idSon"

    t["idSon"] = t["0"];

    //delete your "0" property object

    delete t["0"];

}

//filter based on Id in this example I Used 33275

let filteredData: any = test.filter((o: any) => o["idSon"].idSon == 33275);
```